# Groupby one dataframe based on tags in second dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

i have a dataframe (actually 105k dframes) representation of a SWOT table (should be a 4x4 grid containing strings). The problem is that not all frames in the total set (105k) have the same shape and the position of SWOT elements also varies. My approach is to create a copy of each frame and then look for specific strings in the original frame and add tags to the copy + some forward filling.

Now I have the original frames and copies (same size same indices and same column names), where the original frame has the strings I want to group and a copy that is basically a mask (not boolan - but a mask of tags).

When looping over the whole set I am merging the original frame with the copy based on the index and get a megerd frame that has columns form both frames with _x and _y suffixes. How can I concatenate the strings in columns _y that have the same tag in column _x to a new dataframe?

```
+---+-------+-------------+-------+-------------+-----+-----+
|   | 0_x   | 0_y         | 1_x   | 1_y         | n_x | n_y |
+---+-------+-------------+-------+-------------+-----+-----+
| 0 | tag_1 | some_string | tag_2 | some_string |     |     |
| 1 | tag_1 | some_string | tag_2 | some_string |     |     |
| 2 | tag_2 | some_string | tag_3 | some_string |     |     |
| n | tag_2 | some_string | tag_3 | some_string |     |     |
+---+-------+-------------+-------+-------------+-----+-----+
```

Here is my code so far - basically it does what i want for pairs of columns (n_x, n_y), but it does not work if i have the same tag in more columns (say in 0_x and 1_x). I could do a second iteration over columns a and b and do the same as in the first case, but is there a more efficient way?

df_tmp (cotains the tags) and df_orig (contains the strings)

```
df_merged = pd.merge(df_tmp, df_orig, left_index=True, right_index=True, validate="1:1")
df_merged = df_merged.applymap(str)
columns_list = df_merged.columns.to_list()
x_columns = [elem for elem in columns_list if elem.endswith("x")]
y_columns = [elem for elem in columns_list if elem.endswith("y")]
df_collect = pd.DataFrame()
for col_x, col_y in zip(x_columns, y_columns):
    df_final = df_merged.groupby([col_x])[col_y].apply(','.join).reset_index()
    df_final = df_final.rename(columns={col_x: 'a', col_y: 'b' })
    df_collect = df_collect.append(df_final, ignore_index=True)
```